# Static Key in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

There is a project written by another programmer. And in it there is such a code

```
class CardsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<PaymentCard>()

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        var keyId = 0
    }
}
```

Every time some data is added to the ViewModel, this keyId is incremented:

```
val cardsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())
                    .get(CardsViewModel.keyId.toString(), CardsViewModel::class.java)
                CardsViewModel.keyId++
                cardsViewModel.selected.value = PaymentCard.EMPTY
```

Then gets it this way:

```
val cardsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(CardsViewModel.keyId.toString(), CardsViewModel::class.java)
 bindingId = cardsViewModel.selected.value?.bindingId ?: ""
```

I just recently started learning LiveData and it’s unclear to me what this id gives and how to work with it? I got the impression that I put the data tied to some key and then retrieve it using this key =) But this causes a lot of questions.

P.S. The project was written poorly, so maybe this is some kind of crutch, but due to lack of experience with LiveData, I cannot understand this

Comment: For sure it is bad practice to use static variable, it may cause memory leaks

Comment: But I still do not understand how to work with it in principle?

Comment: instead of that static variable some shared model should be used for accessing key value or even SharedPreferences

Comment: If it is necessary for your project and you dont want to (or dont have time) to change it, just stay with it, but change it to AtomicInteger. About key, as documentation says `key        The key to use to identify the ViewModel.`, so it is just id of ViewModel, probably used in other parts of your project.

Comment: Instead you should use a `viewmodel factory` to pass key id as a constructor param